# Root category template?

Tags: categories

I don't find a way to have a template for my root category page ??

my archive.php file works great for any link such as:

http://adress.com/category/category-name

etc

but for http://adress.com/category/

I can not find the file who could edit that url ? at the moment I just have a 404...

Any idea ? I tried to add a template archive-slug.php without success :(

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: such a template does not exist. what would you expect that a template like that should show?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for answering. It should show all post from all categories, for SEO purpose I ve been told category should have a parent page ! How can it be done ?

Comment: 'all posts of all categories' would be the 'posts page', which is either the home page or a page which you can set via 'settings - reading' ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't find it because it doesn't exist. There is no page at that location.

In WordPress everything is either an archive of posts or a post of some type. Pages are posts of type `page` etc. Date archives are archives of posts

So if you went to `/category` what would it show? For this reason there is nothing there to show. You would need to write a rewrite rule, manually load a template, and that's assuming it doesn't interfere with other rewrite rules

Comment: Thanks Tom, it should show the post of all categories. For SEO purposes I be been told category should have a parent template. How can this be done from rewrite rule ? Thanks :)

Comment: I would consider whoever told you that to be talking complete BS. 27% of the web already works this way with no ill SEO effects. Trust me, you are heading down a *painful* path

Answer (score 0):

Your home page already shows posts from all the categories. The reason that you can't find anything in that path is that `/category/` is a base term for categories, the same way `/tag/` is for tags. You can check this in the permalink page, if you navigate to `Settings > Permalinks`.

There is only 1 condition that you can have a page that list every post from every category, and it's when you have a static home page. In that case, if you navigate to `http://example.com/blog/` you will see a list of every post on your website. If you wish, you can redirect `http://example.com/category/` to `http://example.com/blog/`.

However, be careful not to redirect any other path such as `http://example.com/category/example/`, and make sure you have a static page set as home page, or you will get stuck in an infinite loop.

But as @Tom already mentioned, a quarter of the internet runs on WordPress, and they don't have a SEO problem because of this. So, you can just forget about it ;)